# extract landscape image from any ratio in css

Tags: html, css, image, clip, clip-path

Can anybody tell how to "extract" a landscape image in css from no matter what ratio the image has before?
The Image should not be scaled but being cropped.
The "new image" should contain the center of the inputted image.

CSS:

```
.doesNotWork{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(34, 23, 187);
  /* in my opinion this div should be a square too and display the same content as the other one but a bit bigger to be 50% of the width of the screen*/
}

.worksAsExpected{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(34, 23, 187);
}


.cover {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(187, 23, 23);
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="doesNotWork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/woods.jpg" alt="test" class="cover"/>
</div>
<div class="worksAsExpected">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/woods.jpg" alt="test" class="cover"/>
</div>
```

I made a Codepen that exactly display the issue.
Hope someone can help me with this:

https://codepen.io/su-koch/pen/JjrMqYd

Comment: I'm using object-fit property with value cover now. This works with width and height property of img element in pixles but not in percentage. How can I get this to work with percentage.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far and perhaps add your comment actually into your question as it is very relevant. In particular when you say 'percentage' percentage of what?

Comment: inserted some codepen to make clarification about the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element in the given code has 50% width. This will be 50% of the parent element, in this case body which has taken in viewport width.

The same idea applies to height. It is 50% of the height of the parent. It has no relationship to width.

If you want the two to be linked you can on modern browsers use aspect-ratio. Set width 50% as now, and set aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;

This will give you a square.